# Absolute-positioned div within a div that takes all remaining space

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm trying to make a layout that seems simple. Despite looking at lots of examples, I can't crack it.

```
SideBar| .......MapContainer......
SideBar| ..........Map............
SideBar| .......MapContainer......
```

Both SideBar and MapContainer should be 100% height.

The tricky bit: Map must have a defined height and width, because the mapbox-gl-js library uses its dimensions to populate it. (Rather than adding content which then sizes it).

MapContainer exists because there will be other absolutely positioned overlay elements within it.

I'm trying to avoid having the sidebar width coded into the definition of MapContainer so I can hide/show the sidebar in JS, and have the MapContainer automatically fill the space.

This gets really, really close:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sidebar, .mapcontainer, .container {   
  height: 200px; 
}

.container {
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid;
  display: flex
}
.sidebar {
    width:200px;
    background:lightblue;
}
.mapcontainer {
  width:auto;
  background:lightgreen;
  position:relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position:absolute;  
  border: 20px dashed grey;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="mapcontainer">
      <div class="map">

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But as soon as I change the "height: 200px" to "height: 100%", it collapses to nothing. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use viewport units `vh` instead in the `.sidebar, .mapcontainer, .container` rule

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.sidebar, .mapcontainer, .container {   
  height: 100vh; 
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex
}
.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    background:lightblue;
}
.mapcontainer {
  background:lightgreen;
  position:relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position:absolute;  
  border: 20px dashed grey;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="mapcontainer">
      <div class="map">

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just need to add `height: 100%;` to `html` and `body`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar, .mapcontainer, .container {   
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid;
  display: flex
}
.sidebar {
    width:200px;
    background:lightblue;
}
.mapcontainer {
  width:auto;
  background:lightgreen;
  position:relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position:absolute;  
  border: 20px dashed grey;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="mapcontainer">
      <div class="map">

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```